# Flutter Future and Stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, future, stream-builder

How should I integrate multiple future to build a widget ? I have a group chat screen which builds with streamBuilder and stream is received from a cloud firestore collection "chats". To avoid redundancy chats only contains unique id of sender and msg but to show the name of sender on screen I have to again get senders name from "users" collection using FutureBuilder. This causes significant delay everytime I open chats. is there any better way to implement this ?

Comment: Maybe keep a cache of userid/username pairs instead of going to the datasource every time?

Comment: I thought about caching but there can be multiple servers with many groups with different set of users in each of them (like discord). This is little complicated for me to implement but feels like right thing to do.